# SQL Server equivalent of Oracle standard_hash function

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, migration

I'm moving a database from Oracle to SQL Server and I can't figure out how to create this in SQL Server:

```
"MY_HASH" RAW(32) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (STANDARD_HASH("SSN"||'|'||TO_CHAR("DATE_OF_BIRTH",'DD-MON-RR'),'SHA256')) VIRTUAL ,
```

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: This is a column name in a create table script.

Comment: Hashing is database-dependent.  You can do something similar, but you won't get exactly the same values.

Comment: I edited the title to refer specifically to `standard_hash` as that seemed to be the main technical issue (see my answer). If `to_char` and concatenation are also issues we can amend it to clarify that, but I am assuming those are more straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that in SQL Server you would use the [`hashbytes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/hashbytes-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function passing option 'SHA2_256' to generate the same value as Oracle's [`standard_hash`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/STANDARD_HASH.html) with 'SHA256':

SQL Server 2019 ([DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d144c7860df3b0ff4a3ab433533e7d21)):

```
select hashbytes('SHA2_256','Text')
```

Oracle 18c ([DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f3fb03b2a3bc90efe855353904702ed4)):

```
select standard_hash('Text', 'SHA256') from dual;
```

Both return

```
0x71988C4D8E0803BA4519F0B2864C1331C14A1890BF8694E251379177BFEDB5C3
```

This is a `raw(32)` value in Oracle and `binary(32)` (I think) in SQL Server, not a string, so it may be displayed differently depending on the client tool.

Comment: Thank you, works great